A network related or instance-specific error occurred whilst establishing a connection to SQL Server from Oracle Virtual Box to Host Windows machine
I have deployed an ASP.NET Core Web API to run on an Oracle Virtual Box, but calls to the database fail.
The database is on the host machine that Virtual Box is running on. Other machines on the network can access it so I know that it is shared.
firewall-cmd --list-ports

shows
22/tcp 1433/tcp 5000/tcp

The connection string works when I run the app in the windows host.
Should it be different somehow in Linux?
TCPIP shows as enabled in Configuration Manager

It depends on what network style you use for vBox i think, for example: localhost might point to Virtualbox inner system's network

What's the full and complete text of the error message, including stack trace? As it stands it's possible that your connection string includes an instance name which  requires udp/1434 to be open for SSRP requests and responses (via the SQL Browser service) in addition to whichever TCP ports it may be listening on.
